# How can I connect a signal to different slots according to condition

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a GUI composed by :

- one *QLineEdit()*
- one *QpushButton()*
- two *QlistWidget()*

What I would like to do is to display the text that I have entered on the *QLineEdit()* Widget in one of the lists but with some condition.

When the result entered in the *QLineEdit()* bar is different from the string '10', the GUI dipsplayed the string on the first *QlistWidget()* , it displays one the second list otherwise.

My code is below:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Principale(QMainWindow):


    simpleSig = pyqtSignal(str)


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.search = QPushButton('Search')
        self.TextEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.list = QListWidget()
        self.list1 = QListWidget()

        self.layout0 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout0.addWidget(self.search)
        self.layout0.addWidget(self.TextEdit)

        self.layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.list)
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.list1)

        if self.TextEdit.text().lower() != '10':

            self.simpleSig.connect(self.simpleSlot)

        else:

            self.simpleSig.connect(self.argumentSlot)

        self.GridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.GridLayout.addLayout(self.layout0, 0, 0)
        self.GridLayout.addLayout(self.layout1, 1, 0)

        self.main_Widget = QWidget()
        self.main_Widget.setLayout(self.GridLayout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_Widget)

        self.search.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)


    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.simpleSig.emit(self.TextEdit.text().lower())


    def simpleSlot(self, stringArg):
        self.list.addItem(stringArg)


    def argumentSlot(self, stringArg):
        self.list1.addItem(stringArg)


# Main
monApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
fenetre = Principale()
fenetre.show()
sys.exit(monApp.exec_())
```

Like you see, I used a customized signal and I tried to link it on different slots for achieve different results according to a condition.

**But** it doesn't work, it still display on the fist list whatever the value typed is.

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking the text inside the constructor if lineEdit's value is `10` or not, which is just defined, so it will just have an empty string `''`, if  you have to connect this way, move this part to button clicked function so the text is compared only after button click event, but after every button click, the signal needs to be disconnected first if it is connected, and then needs to be connected again.

Based on your requirement, you don't actually need to connect conditionally, you can just connect it to one function and check the condition inside it, since you are already passing the string argument.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Principale(QMainWindow):


    simpleSig = pyqtSignal(str)


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.search = QPushButton('Search')
        self.TextEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.list = QListWidget()
        self.list1 = QListWidget()

        self.layout0 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout0.addWidget(self.search)
        self.layout0.addWidget(self.TextEdit)

        self.layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.list)
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.list1)
        ##Commented part
        # if self.TextEdit.text().lower() != '10':
        #
        #     self.simpleSig.connect(self.simpleSlot)
        #
        # else:
        #
        #     self.simpleSig.connect(self.argumentSlot)

        self.GridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.GridLayout.addLayout(self.layout0, 0, 0)
        self.GridLayout.addLayout(self.layout1, 1, 0)

        self.main_Widget = QWidget()
        self.main_Widget.setLayout(self.GridLayout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_Widget)

        self.search.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        self.simpleSig.connect(self.simpleSlot)  # Connect the signal to the slot


    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.simpleSig.emit(self.TextEdit.text().lower())


    def simpleSlot(self, stringArg):
        if stringArg != '10':      # Add condition inside the function
            self.list.addItem(stringArg)
        else:
            self.list1.addItem(stringArg)

    ##Commented part
    # def argumentSlot(self, stringArg):
    #     self.list1.addItem(stringArg)


# Main
monApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
fenetre = Principale()
fenetre.show()
sys.exit(monApp.exec_())
```

Comment: It works perfectly thanks ! But I have one question : why you replace the connection between the signal and the slot under the connection between the signal and the function ? Is it important for the compilation ?

Comment: No it's not necessary at all,  it's just a good practice to have all the connections in a single block, so that you can easily find them later in future while debugging/testing/modifying

Comment: Okay no problem, I take note about your advices. Thanks a lot